# STM32CubeMX Two VCPs using CDC

Tags: c, embedded

I'm a beginner in the USB stack on STM32F4.

How do I create a project using STM32CubeMX (STM32F4 Discovery) for USB CDC to have 2 virtual COM ports in [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager)?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the Stack Overflow post *[STM32CubeMX USB CDC VCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549084)*. I think that it will solve your problem

In this post there is a guide about the procedure you can make. Remember to write your code in the **user code** section, otherwise it will be excluded.

And after you created the project, select *Project Settings* in the *Code Generator* tab and make sure that besides the default configuration, select the `Generate peripheral initialization as pair of '.c/.h' files per IP`, to generate the proper project .c files.

Comment: Thank you. I did all what's said but i have only one Virtual COM Port. I need two Virtual COM Ports. Have you ever tried to make two VCPs with only one USB device ?

Comment: Actually no, I only used a serial port/usb converted device and used one com port. I can ask my professor tomorrow and see if he can help. If I find something I'll comment here.