# Which type of USB class is appropriate?

Tags: usb, stm32f4discovery, mpu6050

I am newbie in USB!

I want to read data from MPU6050 using stm32f4discovery. and send data through USB to PC. Which type of USB class is appropriate?

Thanks.

Comment: MPU6050 is an accelerometer/gyroscope module.

Comment: You could use CDC class.

Comment: You need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549084/stm32cubemx-usb-cdc-vcp