# USB device class for generic device

Tags: usb

I am making a custom USB device which will be sending sensor values when requested from the host (i.e. Computer) via USB.

I looked for *Communications and CDC Control* & *CDC-Data* Class, they seemed to do the job and are seen as Virtual COM Port.

Will they be always seen as COM PORT or can be detected something else.

What other class or method is preferable for such example?

[Someone suggested CDC class to similar application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884449/which-type-of-usb-class-is-appropriate)

Note:
Using STM32 microcontroller

Answer (score 0):

That is the idea of the USB classes to be enumerated particular way.  If you want driverless class on any system - I advice HID,